# Generate AngularJS-Controller in subfolder with yeoman

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

i would like to generate all my controllers in my AngularJS-Project with the help of Yeoman.
Unfortunately everything is thrown in the app/scripts/controllers -Folder. Is it possible to say yeoman that the source should be generated in a specific subfolder inside the controllers-folder?

Here is an example:

```
+app
 +scripts
   +controllers
    +part1
       -controller1Ctrl
       -controller2Ctrl
    +part2
       -controller3Ctrl
       -controller4Ctrl
```

Thanks a lot!

-Micha

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best solution or not, but i solved this problem by this command:

`yo angular:controller part1/controller1Ctrl`

hope this will solve your problem too